# How does an A2-rated microSD card perform as adoptable storage in 2023?

Tags: internal-storage, sd-card, storage, app2sd, adoptable-storage

Here's a small backstory. A relative of mine owns a pretty low end Android phone ([Redmi 9T](https://www.gsmarena.com/xiaomi_redmi_9t-10670.php)) running Android 12. They got the 64gb storage variant which, of course, wasn't the best idea since there was a 128gb variant of the phone for not that much more money.

It is what it is, the bottom line now is they got a 128gb SanDisk Extreme that is A2 rated and was asking if it can expand their storage. I told them they can only store photos and videos at best on that card, along with some downloaded files but they wanted to also be able to install more apps.

I was about to suggest they format the card as adoptable storage but upon looking more into it, it seems to be a one-way ticket without any way to revert back. With that in mind, I don't have any idea how it will affect the system's responsiveness as I've never tried it myself.

Based on the specs of the phone that I linked, and the fact that the card is A2-rated, do you think it'll be fine? I've read about some musings on the internet about how A1 rated cards are better than A2 because A2 has more tolerances for slower performance than A1 and A2 relied on certain things the host will do in order to benefit its supposed better performance. However, those discussions happened years ago so now in 2023, has this situation gotten better?

Comment: The internal storage of the 64GB version is UFS 2.1, the sd-card UFS 1.0 and that requires the internal reader also to support UFS, which I am not sure if this is the case in this model.

Comment: @Robert if it does support it, what would that mean for the performance? And is there a way to test it without jumping to adoptable storage immediately?

Comment: May be you are thinking too much about the performance. If the phone user want's more space then give it to them. How much this drains performance is not your problem just warn them that is may happen and that it is a one-way road. I would check if you can find a micro-SD card performance comparison of a trusted source (e.g. technical magazine). In the end IMHO what is even more important is that a micro-SD card can fail much easier which will most likely in data loss. So think about buying a reliable larger card and before first use check 100% the flash memory for functionality!

Comment: You're right. I'll go with that then!